# Recursively remove all keys with empty arrays and objects in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON input:

```json
{
  "a": {
    "a": "foo",
    "b": "bar"
  },
  "b": {
    "a": [],
    "b": []
  },
  "c": {},
  "d": [
    "foo",
    "bar"
  ]
}
```

I want to recursively remove all the keys that point at empty arrays or objects, so that the result looks like:

```json
{
  "a": {
    "a": "foo",
    "b": "bar"
  },
  "d": [
    "foo",
    "bar"
  ]
}
```

What I've come up with is:

`jq 'walk(if ((type=="object" or type=="array") and length==0) then empty else . end)'`

But this deletes everything but the last array:

```json
{
  "d": [
    "foo",
    "bar"
  ]
}
```

If I change `empty` to `{"A":1}`:

`jq 'walk(if ((type=="object" or type=="array") and length==0) then {"A":1} else . end)'`

I get what I expect, where the first, populated object remains untouched:

```json
{
  "a": {
    "a": "foo",
    "b": "bar"
  },
  "b": {
    "a": {
      "A": 1
    },
    "b": {
      "A": 1
    }
  },
  "c": {
    "A": 1
  },
  "d": [
    "foo",
    "bar"
  ]
}
```

So why is it when I instead tell it to replace zero-length arrays and objects with `empty` that it attacks non-zero-length objects? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> remove all the keys that point at empty arrays or objects

Here's a solution using `walk` and `IN`:

```
walk( if type == "object" 
      then with_entries(select(.value | IN([],{}) | not ) ) 
      else . end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
def f: recurse | select(IN([], {}));
until(isempty(f); del(f))
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/TmGR6JbiLN-)</sup>